# Automatically link to a cell in another sheet if value is the same

Tags: excel

I have a status update sheet (sheet1) in which team members have a line per action, and each action has a reference number (s1, columnA).

[image]

In another sheet (sheet2), I have the team leads write their own status updates, but they may not necessarily reference every single reference number, nor will they do it in the same order as sheet1.

[image]

Basically, what I'm looking for is a column in sheet1 to show a link automatically IF the reference number in columnA sheet1 is also found somewhere in columnB in sheet2.

Is this possible? If so, how would I work this? I'm hoping to use a formula, but I'm not sure if that's possible. Hoping to use VBA as a last resort since this will be a shared spreadsheet and the probability that someone might screw it up is decent.

Thank you, and please let me know if I should clarify anything.

Comment: Seems like an ordinary case for `VLoopUp` or `Index/Match`. If not, please elaborate a bit more (possibly with screenshots of the current state and the desired end result.

Comment: So [here](http://imageshack.com/a/img924/7236/vXCWSN.png) is the first sheet. Note the reference number there. What I'm wanting is for that to link automatically (or I can create another empty column for the link to populate if necessary, doesn't matter) link to the cell that includes the same reference number in [this spreadsheet](http://imageshack.com/a/img923/9451/BXkUZP.png). Basically so that the team lead could type in that same reference number in their issues/delays column and it would link automatically to the corresponding entry on the other sheet. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Basically, I'm wanting to avoid making my users create a hyperlink to another cell and am hoping to have it created automatically when the corresponding number is entered in the second sheet, since they're highly unlikely to use the hyperlink process.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying comments and screenshots. I think now I understand and will post a solution based on that.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a dynamic hyperlink.

So, let's assume that you have on `Sheet1` all the

- team members with the (column `B`)
- team leads and the (column `A`)
- reference / project numbers (column `C`).

On `Sheet2` we have a table with various information and the same reference / project number in column `E`.

Then you can add a new column `D` to the table on `Sheet1` which you might want to name `Links` and the formula here should be:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!E"&MATCH(D2,Sheet2!E:E,0),"Link to "&D2)
```

If you are using tables with named columns that you can also use:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!E"&MATCH([@[Reference Number]],Sheet2!E:E,0),"Link to "&[@[Reference Number]])
```

<sub>Of course you can adjust the *alternative text* to something more suitable.</sub>

Maybe the following picture helps explaining the above:

[image]