# Excel VBA: How to autocreate hyperlink from cell value?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a table called Table1

In Column B, I have the ticket number. e.g: 76537434

Requirement: when any change happens in any cell in column B, that cell (Target cell) to be changed into a hyperlink such that the hyperlink address would be example.com/id=76537434

Cell value i.e. 76537434 must remain the same

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA and a simple `Hyperlink()` function call in a separate helper-column would be fine then you can also go with a solution similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977982/automatically-link-to-a-cell-in-another-sheet-if-value-is-the-same/42984060#42984060#

Comment: Thanks Ralph but I wanted the Hyperlink to be on the same cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this event handler to your worksheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub
    Target.Hyperlinks.Delete ' or Target.ClearHyperlinks to conserve the formatting
    Me.Hyperlinks.Add Target, "http://example.com/id=" & Target.value
End Sub
```

Comment: Simplest and neat solution

Comment: use Target.ClearHyperlinks instead of Target.Hyperlinks.Delete

Comment: @Dv_MH good suggestion, ClearHyperlinks conserves the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

The following `Worksheet_Change` event should be able to solve your problem:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell As Range
Dim tmp As String
If Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each cell In Target
    If cell.Column = 2 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        tmp = cell.Value2
        cell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=Cells(cell.Row, 2), _
            Address:="http://example.com/id=" & tmp, _
            TextToDisplay:=tmp
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Note, that you must copy it to the sheet and **not** into a separate module.

Answer (score 0):

```
=HYPERLINK(E14&F14,"Name")
```

where cell E14 contains "http://www.example.com/id=" and cell F14 contains "76537434".
This soultions doesn't need VBA macros.