# conditional hyperlink to other dynamic sheet

Tags: excel

[image]

[image]

I would like to create hyperlink to focus correspondent cell. If a person clicks a Week number in the **Main** sheet, I would like to focus to correct person's sheet and select the start of that week.

Is this possible? 
Thanks

Comment: Look at `Worksheet_SelectionChange` events.

Comment: Either one of these solutions should work (or both combined): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977982/automatically-link-to-a-cell-in-another-sheet-if-value-is-the-same/42984060#42984060 AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092315/excel-vba-how-to-autocreate-hyperlink-from-cell-value/43092828#43092828