# Build hyperlink with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, office365

Here is my formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'VLOOKUP(H2;'Phones'!A9:S71;2;FALSE)'";"1")
```

I'm getting an error that Reference is invalid. Please assist.

Thanks

Comment: What's the expected result? Are you trying to hyperlink to the Phones sheet row containing the same value as H2?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Once I click on H2 I`m trying to point to the Phone sheet and find a cell with the H2 value.

Comment: Like this probably: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977982/automatically-link-to-a-cell-in-another-sheet-if-value-is-the-same. You don't want to use `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Great example, thank you. Works fine!